# JSON to Array using PHP json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm reading a json file using

```
$jsonStr = file_get_contents("connection.json");
$jsonParsed = json_decode($jsonStr,true);
```

and I want $jsonParsed to be a associative array like this:

```
$jsonParsed = { "SERVER" => "111.222.333.444" , "USER" => "edvaldo" , "PASSWORD" => "my_password_here", "DATABASE" => "my_database_here" };
```

What is the format of the JSON needed to do this?

I tried this

```
{
    "SERVER": "111.222.333.444",
    "USER": "edvaldo",
    "PASSWORD": "my_password_here",
    "DATABASE": "my_database_here"
}
```

but even with JSONLint saying this piece og JSON is valid, I can't get the result I need.

I'm not really very used to JSON and then I will appreciate a lot any help given.

EDITED:

This is the function I'm using:

```
private function set_mysql_parameters() {
    $this->connectionParams = array();
    $json_file = $this->system_paths["JSONDATA"] . "connection.json";
    $json_mysql = file_get_contents($json_file);
    $json_parsed = json_decode($json_file,true,250);
    foreach($json_parsed as $key => $value) {
        $this->connectionParams[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

My goal is to fill this array $this->connectionParams with data extracted from the JSON file.

Comment: Works fine: https://eval.in/408693

Comment: Also works: https://eval.in/408694

Comment: Not here, unfortunately, @Jessica. I get a NULL, like if the JSON were malformed.

Comment: are you  sure `$jsonStr` contains what you think it does

Comment: Then you need to post your actual code - without actual passwords and stuff.

Comment: most likely there is an issue with the file reading.  It the unaccounted for.  Also php arrays don't have `array{key=>value}` format.

Comment: `echo json_last_error( )` after the decode.

Comment: @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. - that IP seems to be invalid. `Sorry, we couldn't find any name servers for~`

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, of course it is! It's a fake IP I used here to protect the information abour my server. Of course, this is not the reason of the failure.

Comment: @frz3993, I tried it and it just printed "4"... What's the meaning of this?

Comment: @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. again if you print the json from your php variable that it is loaded into, is  it actually your Json, for all we know `$this->system_paths["JSONDATA"]` has no slash  at the end.  Maybe it has 251 nested elements.

Comment: @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. for syntax error.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix the slash is there and the JSON file is being read. This is not the problem. It is the conversion.

Comment: @frz3993 Yeah, I checked the PHP docs and 4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX. But when I verify with JSONLint, my JSON is valid!

Comment: here is your error  An invalid UTF8 sequence, see example #2 http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: I notice you are trying to decode the filename @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. not the file content.

Comment: @frz3993 Exact! Thanks a lot! This is the kind of thing hard to see. Thank you a lot. Please post this as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you are trying to decode the filename instead of the content.

```
$json_file = $this->system_paths["JSONDATA"] . "connection.json";
$json_parsed = json_decode($json_file,true,250);
```

Shouldn't it be

```
$json_parsed = json_decode($json_mysql, true, 250);
```